how to can i add Android TV support on my Phone App?
i have an App which i developed for Tablet/Phone now i want to add Android TV support.
i tried many ways but failed
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start
i tried follow this two method but failed.
Can we create application which run on Android TV ,tablet and Android Phones?
according this stackoverflow i modified my manifest file but when i run on Android tv Emulator, Emulator cannot recognize if its phone or tv app it lunch phone version while i want tv version to lunch on TV Emulator and phone version on Phone Emulator.
anyone have and multi device App?
if yes how to develop an app which support tv and phone (i mean when i run on tv, TV layouts should open which designed special for tv and on phone, phone layout )
i tried to add android tv Support on my App.
and i expect someone who already has such App help me

All you have to do is add the leanback intent filter to your manifest
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
and then add a new banner icon and it should show in the apps list of your launcher. If you want specific layouts then you need to use the specified layout folders for tv's

this what i did. but when i run on Emulator, Emulator cannot recognize if its Phone or Tv  version it always run phone version

then you are not using the correct folder types to the tv specific layouts

i uploaded the project on Github
can you give a look on it please and see where is my mistake
https://github.com/forotan1/TvAndPhone

You have a lot wrong in that repo. First your main activity you have listed in your manifest is your compose activity not the view. Second, decide if you are using compose or the view system. Third, like I said earlier you are not using the correct layout folders (if you are going to use the view system) for tv layouts. I suggest you look at this link on how to create different layout folders for different screen types https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
